# Any instance access all instances (of a class)

Tags: c++, object, instance

This may seem like a trivial question, or I may have misunderstood previous information/the research I've done so far.

But is it possible to have a object with a function (in C++) that can access all instances of its own type?

In the context of my usage. I wanted to have a `Button` class, whereby I could simply instantiate multiple `Buttons` but call to a function could call reference all buttons.

```
ButtonInstance.isMouseTargetting(cursorCoordinates);
```

Is this possible? If so is it efficient?

Or should I have the class which owns the `Button` instances call each instance to check if the mouse coordinates match up?

Comment: You can code whatever you want. The constructor, for example, could add the new instance to a collection and the destructor could remove it. Then you can access the collection however you want.

Comment: There is no language support for directly do this, but as long as you keep all your button in the same place you can just iterate through them and call isMouseTargetting function in all one by one.

Comment: So if I had a protected container, could all instances of `Button` access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm under the impression you are looking for advice on how to design this.

> In the context of my usage. I wanted to have a Button class, whereby I
>   could simply instantiate multiple Buttons but call to a function could
>   call reference all buttons.

You want to do this in a button container.  A button is not a button container and in a GUI context you already have an established hirerarchy.

> Or should I have the class which owns the Button instances call each
>   instance to check if the mouse coordinates match up?

Yes. You probably already have a window/container class for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more of about Design pattern than C++ itself. Take a look at the Gang of Four book;you will find an appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, make a list of all objects created for a given class,

```
class Button {
public:
    Button() {
        _buttonList.push_back( this );
        // assign index/handler to this button
    }
    ~Button() {
        _buttonList.erase( _handle );
    }

    static bool isMouseTargeting( float x, float y ) {
        for ( auto button : _buttonList ) {
            // check if inside
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    static std::list< Button* > _buttonList;
    // Handler _handle;
}
```

This is only a very general example of what you could do. You can use any other container besides a list (entirely up to you), and you have to find a way to index each button (or create a [handle](http://gamesfromwithin.com/managing-data-relationships)) so that you can later erase it in the destructor.

Beware of the default constructors (copy or move). If you don't explicitly create your constructors then some of your buttons will not enter the list, so either make them yourself or delete them.

```
Button( const Button& button ) = delete;
```

This is one way to do what you asked, but not necessarily the best solution. It may be simpler to just add the buttons to a non-static container by yourself and search from there.

Comment: So a static variable will reference the same location in memory across any instance of the class?

Comment: @OliverGiess Correct. It will work like a global variable. If it were public you could even access it (the same memory location) from outside the class. Just don't forget to both declare it in the header file and define it in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. But i will not recommend to put this functionality on the Button class since this will add extra (maybe not expected) responsibility to it. You can achieve the desired behavior by storing your Button objects on some collection and then call a function to check which button is targeted by the mouse.

Another solution would be to store the buttons collection as a member of a higher level class that represents your user-interface. This way you can call a method of this class and check if the mouse cursor is currently on some Button or not. With this design you can add the same support for other GUI elements (if you need to) easily.